# preg_split string with negative look-behind assertion php

Tags: php, regex, string, split, preg-match

this is array i have

```
 Array
    (

        [0] =>                  string@:abc:-------:abc
        [1] =>                  string@:abc:xyz-----:abc
        [2] =>               string1:string2:abc:xyz-----:abc                               
        [3] =>               string2:string3:abc:xyz-----:abc            
     )
```

i want to split these offset like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1st] =>                  String@
            [2nd] => abc
            [3rd] => ------
            [4th] => abc
        )

   [1] => Array
        (
            [1st] =>                  String@
            [2nd] => abc
            [3rd] => xyz
            [4th] => abc
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1st] =>                  String1
            [2nd] => string2
            [3rd] => abc
            [4th] => xyz
            [5th]=> abc
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [1st] =>                  String2
            [2nd] => string3
            [3rd] => abc
            [4th] => xyz
            [5th]=> abc
        )

)
```

my problem is in 2,3 array string1 and string2 are coming in diff offset i want like this

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [1st] =>     String1:string2
            [2rd] => abc
            [3th] => xyz
            [4th]=> abc
        )
  [1] => Array
        (
            [1st] =>     String2:string3
            [2rd] => abc
            [3th] => xyz
            [4th]=> abc
        )
```

but there is only two special char @ nd : if in string1 @ is not there i want to split from start ,if @ is not there i want to start after string2
please help

Comment: What's your question? I.e. where's the code with which you're having your problem?

Comment: my question is i have a string= "string1:string2:abc:fd-----:abc";       i want to split this with : char but not after string1,i want o split after string2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use this negative lookbehind:

```
$arr = preg_split('/(?<!(?:string1|string2)):/', 'string1:string2:abc:xyz-----:abc');
var_dump($arr);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "string1:string2"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "abc"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "xyz-----"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "abc"
}
```

Comment: thnku anubhava,it is working but in ,$arr = preg_split('/(?<!string1):/', 'string1:string2:abc:xyz-----:abc');                       string1 is not fixed ,it can be any thing....how to fix this

Comment: You need to clarify your question properly. What are all the cases when `:` should not be used in split.

Comment: can you tell me how to pass two parameter together where you passing only single string1,i need to pass two string1 nd string2 then it will help

Comment: Your comment isn't clear to me. There is a reason so many downvotes happened on your question. I am asking you to clarify it properly to get good answer.

Comment: Array
    (

        [0] =>                  string@:abc:-------:abc
        [1] =>                  string@:abc:xyz-----:abc
        [2] =>               string1:string2:abc:xyz-----:abc                                                        
        [3] =>               string2:string3:abc:xyz-----:abc               now how to solve this in preg split u are matching with this string: ,but if there is another string in next offset of array ,it will not split 3 offset according to ur preg_split condition

Comment: So why should `abc:xyz` not split on colon?

Comment: sir your preg_split is working just problem in that is you are spliting string where it has this "string1:",if this string1 will come in array it will give good ,but if it has some diffrent string then it will not help,i did nt get you question,i need split every string after colon but there is condition if @is not present with string1 then i need  to concatenate this string1: with next string2,plz just help me if possible to pass two string in you preg_split condition like this    $arr = preg_split('/(?<!string1,string2):/', 'string1:string2:abc:xyz-----:abc');

Comment: Problem is that you are not explaining rules for splitting clearly. What is your expected output from `string1:string2:abc:xyz-----:abc`?

Comment: like u sent me ,this is ur output                                array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "string1:string2"
 
}                                                            array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "string2:string3"
 
}                                                                    i have a question u sent me preg_split condition ,ok there u r splitting with string1: ,but if i want to add one more string with string:1,is it possible to add two parameters in preg_split

Comment: thnku veru much anubhava for ur help ,atleast you got my question even i m shocked i clearly mention this is array ,this is coming output and i want this output,nd stil lots of guys did nt get,but thnku for your help nd sry i did nt tell u ,in preg_split it can be split with randomly string.               thnku

Comment: thnku for update but it is giving error but i modified little bit and this is working fine /(?<!string1|string2):/' and u sent me that is giving this--- Warning: preg_split() [function.preg-split]: Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length –